# Snowflake - Making a mistake while wrapping a transaction properly in the begin end block

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking for help with surrounding a transaction with a begin/end block. Here is my code:

```
CREATE or REPLACE PROCEDURE fullvsdeltaload(reload number)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE sql 
EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
$$

    BEGIN
        
        LET reload_val INT := :reload;

        if (reload_val = 0)   -- do a full load
        THEN
        BEGIN
        create or replace table drop_and_recreate_main_table  
            (
            ..
            ..
            )
            AS
            WITH 
            ..   ;

        COMMIT; 

        RETURN 'Success fully reloading the main table' ;
        
        ELSEIF  (reload_val = 1) THEN  -- do a delta load
        
        BEGIN
        create or replace table delta_table_with_changed_records 
            (
                ..
            )
            AS
            WITH 
            .. ;
        
        MERGE INTO main_table 
        USING delta_table 
            ON ..
            AND ..
                WHEN MATCHED THEN 
                    UPDATE SET ..
                        WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
                            INSERT ..
                            VALUES ..;
    
        COMMIT;
            
        RETURN 'Success merging changed records into the main table' ;     
        END IF;

       EXCEPTION

        WHEN STATEMENT_ERROR THEN
        ROLLBACK; 
        
        let errMsg string:= OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('SUCCESS', FALSE,
                                'ERROR TYPE', 'STATEMENT_ERROR',
                                'SQLCODE', SQLCODE,
                                'SQLERRM', SQLERRM,
                                'SQLSTATE', SQLSTATE);  
        RETURN  errMsg;
                    
                                
        WHEN EXPRESSION_ERROR THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        
        let errMsg string:= OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('SUCCESS', FALSE,
                                'ERROR TYPE', 'EXPRESSION_ERROR',
                                'SQLCODE', SQLCODE,
                                'SQLERRM', SQLERRM,
                                'SQLSTATE', SQLSTATE);     
        RETURN  errMsg;    
                                
        WHEN OTHER THEN
        ROLLBACK;
        
        let errMsg string:= OBJECT_CONSTRUCT('SUCCESS', FALSE,
                                'ERROR TYPE', 'OTHER',
                                'SQLCODE', SQLCODE,
                                'SQLERRM', SQLERRM,
                                'SQLSTATE', SQLSTATE);  
             
        RETURN  errMsg;      
    END;
$$
;
```

When I run the stored procedure with a reload_val = 1 (for delta load) as a Snowflake task, it executes the commit after the merge statement, but then goes into the exception block, and complains with a statement error. Not sure why that is happening.

Can you please let me know if I need to supply some additional "begin transaction" statements so that it commits properly and then exits the stored proc?

Please advise.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: creating tables ends the existing transaction. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions#ddl

Comment: Hello Simeon! Thanks for your reply. I was able to resolve this issue by changing the "create or replace table" clause with the "insert overwrite" clause, which does a truncate and insert in the same command. And I am persisting the table structures in the database instead of replacing them each time (my table structures will stay consistent).